# Static nested class as generic type bound doesn't work

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea

File **AbstractContainer.java**

```
package container;

import static container.AbstractContainer.*;

public abstract class AbstractContainer<ElementType extends AbstractElement> {
    public static abstract class AbstractElement {
    }
}
```

File **ConcreteElement.java**

```
package container;

import static container.ConcreteContainer.*;
import static container.AbstractContainer.*;

public class ConcreteContainer extends AbstractContainer<ConcreteElement> {
    public static class ConcreteElement extends AbstractElement {
    }
}
```

This code gives me a compile error:

```
java: type argument container.ConcreteContainer.ConcreteElement is not within bounds of type-variable ElementType
```

but the IDE doesn't see any problems (IDEA 12).

First: What is going on here?

Second question, In **AbstractContainer.java** why do I have to static import the nested class, that's obviously in scope, to use it in the generic type (`extends AbstractElement` instead of `extends AbstractContainer.AbstractElement`) ?

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't have to static-import the class.  Just qualify the reference to your inner classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractContainer<ElementType extends 
    AbstractContainer.AbstractElement> {
```

and

```
public class ConcreteContainer extends 
    AbstractContainer<ConcreteContainer.ConcreteElement>
```

When compiling with Java 1.6, I don't see your compiler error.  But I do see it when compiling with 1.7.

As it happens, fully-qualifying `AbstractElement` when declaring `ConcreteElement` seems to satisfy the compiiler:

```
public class ConcreteContainer extends 
    AbstractContainer<ConcreteContainer.ConcreteElement> {
                                           // fully qualify here
    public static class ConcreteElement extends AbstractContainer.AbstractElement {
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding first: but why do I have to import static to **not** fully qualify the name? Inside the class I dont have to do that. Regarding second part: what does the fully qualified name change? I had a static import!

Answer (score 1):

First question - probably a compiler bug.

Second question - probably due to technicality:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3

> The scope of a declaration of a member `m` declared in or inherited by a class type C (§8.1.6) is the entire body of C

For example

```
@SomeAnnotation(M.class)
class C
<T extends M>
{
    static class M{}
}
```

the code is illegal, because `M` is used outside the body of `C`, in annotation, and in type parameter.

Prior to Java 5, there's no annotation/generics, therefore "the entire body of C" covers all places "M" can be sensibly referenced. But now the rule is outdated, we should really extend the scope of `M` a little bit; I don't see any problem in doing that.

Comment: *we should really extend the scope of M* - by *we* you mean the Java community / language design team? Thanks for the answer