# Java Generics and overridding

Tags: java, generics

Why does the following happen:

```
public class one{
   public <T extends Foo> Bar<Foo> function1() {}
   public Bar<Foo> function2(){}
}
```

```java
public class two<F extends Foo> extends one{
   public Bar<F> function1(){} //Doesn't throw an error
   public Bar<F> function2(){} //Throws an error
}
```

By saying `<T extends Foo>` am I saying that Foo can be overridden with a super type?

Note:  My question is **not** why `function2()` throws an error...but why `function1()` *doesn't* throw an error.

Comment: `public <T extends Foo> Bar<Foo> function1() {}` does this compile? I don't know what that return type is.

Comment: `Bar<Foo>` is the return type.  And yes it compiles.

Comment: Two public classes in one file?

Comment: the return type here looks like `<T extends Foo> Bar<Foo>` to me

Comment: No, different files, just making it short and easy to understand.

Comment: @Cruncher The first part is a generic type declaration for the method. `Bar<Foo>` is the return type.

Comment: @MrTi this is a *strange* piece of code. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @elmes I think he's intrigued by it, and wants to know why it works(for function 1).

Comment: @elmes I want to return a ListIterator of the class I'm extending that already has a ListIterator

Comment: @MrTi you probably could make `one` generic and extend `one<T>` and not `one` alone. *Curiously recurring template pattern* and the like.

Comment: I do not want to do `one<T extends one<T>>`.  One is much too common in my code, and I don't want to have to make widespread changes.

Comment: this is not compiling.... _the retunr type is incompatible_

Comment: @MrTi have you heard about covariance and contravariance etc? I can elaborate on the subject here.

Comment: @PhilippSander are you referring to function1 or 2?  I know that function2 doesn't compile, but function1 is compiling just fine for me.

Comment: @MrTi in this case i mean function2 .. but function1 is also not compiling because of the missing return statement

Comment: It looks to me like the functions in Class two should completely override those in Class one ... irrespective of the differences in return type.  The answer probably has to do with return type, but as I understand overriding, I cannot understand why the reported error is reported only for one of the overriding functions.

Comment: `<T extends Foo>` is actually nonsensical.  The bounded type parameter is never used in the method body or the signature and, so, could be omitted entirely with no change in meaning.

Comment: @scottb If you remove it, the code for `function1()` doesn't compile.

Comment: That's what I though, scottb...but it makes a difference as to whether it compiles.

Comment: If you add the @Override annotations to the functions of class two does the compiler report errors regarding overriding?

Comment: @scottb Nope, it's the correct method.

Comment: Yes, I'm adding @Override, but either way, I get the same result.

Comment: I can't understand it.  As I see things, (particularly since @Override reports no error) Class two has no dependence on Class one whatsoever.  I do not see an error in the method definitions for either of the functions.

Comment: Class two extends Class one.  That is why I should be getting errors for both methods.

Comment: But the functions of Class two override those in Class one and there are no calls to `super` ... so functionally, the meaning of Class two is the same with or without extends.  Class two has overridden all the members of Class one with its own.

Comment: Oh, there's plenty of more code I haven't shown you.  But its irrelevant, which is why I'm not showing you it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably a compiler bug.

The reason that `Two.function1` is considered an overriding method of `One.function1` is from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2

> the signature of `Two.function1` is the same as the erasure of the signature of `One.function1`.

This is to allow legacy subtype (Two) still compile after a supertype (One) is generified.

After that, javac needs to check the return type:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3

> If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the declaration of another method d2 with return type R2, then d1 must be return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for d2, or a compile-time error occurs.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5

> R1 is either a subtype of R2 or R1 can be converted to a subtype of R2 by unchecked conversion (§5.1.9), or R1 = |R2|

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9

> There is an unchecked conversion from the raw class or interface type (§4.8) G to any parameterized type of the form G.

Unchecked conversion does not apply here where `R1=Bar<F>, R2=Bar<Foo>`. That's why Javac reports that `function2` return type is conflicting.

Javac should report the same error for `function1`. I'm guessing that in a previous step, javac took the erasure of `One.function1`, which is `Bar function1()`, and mistakenly uses that version to check against `Two.function1` - here `R2=Bar`, therefore `R1` is a subtype($4.10.2) of `R2`, therefore the return type is compatible. (However, if that theory is correct, there shouldn't be a "unchecked" warning)

Answer (score 3):

The method `function2` is not generic. It returns a `Bar<Foo>`.

Subclasses may return subclasses of return types in overridden methods. This is called a *covariant return type*.

But `Bar<F>` is not a subclass of `Bar<Foo>`, even if `F` subclasses `Foo` - generics are not covariant in Java (arrays are, though).

---

My IDE actually warns me about `function1` too: *Unchecked overriding: return type requires unchecked conversion*. I believe this is only a warning because of the sole existence of a generic type in base class and type erasure. I'd say you're operating on non-generic `Bar`s anyway here..

Comment: A please now explain for `function1()`.

Comment: It looks to me that Class two could -not- extend Class one and the meaning of Class two would still be the same.  To me it is a very peculiar error.

Comment: The generic type on `function1` is not used.

Comment: If I look at it from only Class one's point of view...the generic type isn't doing *anything*.

Comment: It seems that I don't understand erasure.  What difference would `<T extends Foo>` make on erasure?

Comment: Defining type parameters on a method marks it as a generic method. That will alter the way it's handled.

Comment: Well this might simply be some kind of a compiler bug, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497138/static-nested-class-as-generic-type-bound-doesnt-work Not directly related, but unexplained either..

Answer (score 2):

`<T extends Foo>` defines a type `T` that must be some subtype of `Foo`. This isn't actually used anywhere in `one` or `two`.

My guess is this is because how the compiler is erasing the types for the functions is being handled differently since there is a generic type definition scoped to `one.function1()`.

Looking at the [JLS 8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3) defines valid method override. There is an example a bit down about the "unchecked conversion" warning. In there, it links to [8.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5) describing what is "return-type-substitutable" and from there to [5.1.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9) about unchecked conversions.

I do not have an answer, but it appears that something about tagging that method as a generic method (not just a method using a parameterized type) triggers allowing the unchecked conversion to be done - whether intentionally or because of a bug.

Edit: Given

```
public class Main {
  class Bar<X> {}
  class Foo{}
  class one{
   public <T extends Foo> Bar<Foo> function1() { return null; }
   public Bar<Foo> function2(){ return null; }
  }
  class two<F extends Foo> extends one{
   public Bar<F> function1(){ return null; } //Doesn't throw an error
   public Bar<F> function2(){ return null; } //Throws an error
  }
}
```

Compiling with `javac -Xlint:unchecked Main.java`:

```
Main.java:9: warning: [unchecked] function1() in Main.two overrides <T>function1() in Main.one
   public Bar<F> function1(){ return null; } //Doesn't throw an error
                 ^
  return type requires unchecked conversion from Main.Bar<F> to Main.Bar<Main.Foo>
  where F,T are type-variables:
    F extends Main.Foo declared in class Main.two
    T extends Main.Foo declared in method <T>function1()
Main.java:10: error: function2() in Main.two cannot override function2() in Main.one
   public Bar<F> function2(){ return null; } //Throws an error
                 ^
  return type Main.Bar<F> is not compatible with Main.Bar<Main.Foo>
  where F is a type-variable:
    F extends Main.Foo declared in class Main.two
1 error
1 warning
```

Comment: Well, at least you are getting a warning on function1(), which is more than I'm getting.  It makes me wonder whether <T extends Foo> tells the compiler to convert somehow.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I've run into problems with how generic types are handled between the Sun/Oracle JDK & the Eclipse JDK.

Comment: jdk1.7.0_17 on eclipse.  What were those problems you ran into?

Comment: One compiler would compile code with generics in it without issues and the other would exit with an error. I'd recommend compiling this example from the command line to see if you can get the warning that way.